# Problem sending WAXP from Kucoin to MEW

Tags: transactions

Hope I'm in the right place.

In sending WAXP from Kucoin to MEW, I encounter error number one which tells me my MEW address contains sensitive or erroneous information. This only happens when I send WAXP.  Further notes tell me an address has been detected but that I should 'please withdraw via chain'. I don't have the slightest idea what this means.  What is 'chain'?  I've thumbed through on-line tutorials and YouTubes til I'm blue.  I only know one thing to do that works with every coin I've sent from Kucoin to MEW.  However, in my case at least, that **one thing** doesn't work for WAXP.  Does anyone out there in community land have a clue to the a definition of 'withdraw via chain' or directions to a workaround for this?

Thanks a million for the help!

Noob

Comment: Maybe it means 'withdraw via blockchain', i.e., interact directly with the contract instead of via some (off-chain) app like MEW.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.  Something new to learn...